# Android alarm manager not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Ok so I am having an issue and i was hoping i could get some help with it.

The issue i am having is I cannot get an android alarm manager event to activate, even though it seems to be functionally the same as i've seen others use. There is no logcat output to suggest it is an error.

I will attach my code below, any help would be appreciated.

Adding onclick to buttons (where i want the manager to activate from)

```
 public void setOnClick() {
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent alarm = new Intent(getContext(), ActionHandler.class);
            alarm.putExtra("event", event);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, alarm, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,1000*2*60, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 1, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
            //alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 30, pi);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 1000 * 60,
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "buttong pushed for event " + event.eventName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.daniel.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="ActionHandler"></receiver>
    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Alarm listener

```
public class ActionHandler extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Event event = (Event)intent.getSerializableExtra("event");
        Log.d("the listener event", "i have entered the event as " + event.eventName);
        Toast.makeText(null, "hi, i'm an event called " + event.eventName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Event Button Constructor (class extends Button)

```
public EventButton(Context context, Event pEvent) {
        super(context);
        eventDate = pEvent.eventDate;
        eventName = pEvent.eventName;
        eventHost = pEvent.eventHost;
        eventLocation = pEvent.eventLocation;
        event = pEvent;
        startingColor = button.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();

        if (FileManager.compare(event)) {
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            button.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
        }

        setOnClick();

        this.setText(eventName + "\n " + eventHost);
    }
```

Creating a new Button (called from main activity on create)

```
public void addButtonToList(String pHost, String pName,String pEventLocation, Calendar pDate){
        Event event = new Event(pHost, pName, pEventLocation, pDate);
        buttons.add(new EventButton(this, event));
    }
```

Comment: Why did you changed the process to ":remote" for your receiver ?

Comment: that was me trying to follow instructions to try get it to work that i probably mis understood

Comment: Can you try removing that attribute and check ?

Comment: From where are you getting getContext() ?

Comment: <receiver android:name="ActionHandler"></receiver>

i changed it to that but still no luck

Comment: I the buttons class I have extends Button so it takes in a context which is passed from my main activity when they're created

Comment: So, you are calling setOnClick() from Button class ?

Comment: it's called in the constructor, i'll post that to the main post

Comment: Can you post the statement where  you created EventButton instance ?

Comment: ok i added the constructor and how it's the button's created

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108222/discussion-between-shadab-ansari-and-daniel).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setInexactRepeating (int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)


Schedule a repeating alarm that has inexact trigger time requirements; for example, 
an alarm that repeats every hour, but not necessarily at the top of every hour. 
These alarms are more power-efficient than the strict recurrences traditionally supplied 
by setRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent), since the system can adjust alarms' 
delivery times to cause them to fire simultaneously, avoiding waking the device from sleep 
more than necessary.

Your alarm's first trigger will not be before the requested time, but it might not occur 
for almost a full interval after that time. In addition, while the overall period of the 
repeating alarm will be as requested, the time between any two successive firings of the 
alarm may vary. If your application demands very low jitter, use one-shot alarms with an 
appropriate window instead;
```

Simply put. You 're setting the alarm to go off for the first time at one minute after the epoch which was at January 1, 1970 and fire every 24 hours after that. Ofcourse th first fire does not happen...

Do this instead:

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+1000 * 60,
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

And pay attention to the interval period. Are you sure you want it to fire every 24 hours ?